# Import update into WSUS by .msu file

Tags: windows-update

I have a Windows6.2-KB2712101-x86 update file cannot find it on Windows Update Catalog.But can find the x64 version.

So, cannot import it's x86 version into WSUS by Windows Update Catalog using PowerShell.

I can download the x86 version .msu file from Microsoft Download Center. Can I import the update by .msu directly?

I tried use 7Zip to view the .msu package content.

Windows6.2-KB2712101-x86.xml in the package is not look like the vaild data for WSUS use. And the package.xml in the WSUSSCAN.cab in the package file, it's content like able use for WSUS but not complete.